# JSONDecodeError when trying to read and format multiple json files in a directory in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-os

I am trying to read and format multiple json files in a directory using Python. I have created a function load_json_to_dataframe to load and format the json data into a pandas dataframe, and another function read_json_files to read and append each dataframe to a list. However, I keep getting a JSONDecodeError when I run the code.

Here is the code I am using:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import json

def load_json_to_dataframe(json_file_path):
    with open(json_file_path, 'r') as json_file:
        doc = json.load(json_file)
        return pd.json_normalize(doc)

def read_json_files(folder_path):
    dataframes = []
    json_files = os.listdir(folder_path)
    for json_file in json_files:
        if json_file.endswith('.json'):
            df = load_json_to_dataframe(os.path.join(folder_path, json_file))
            dataframes.append(df)
    return pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)

folder_path = 'path/to/json/files'
combined_dataframe = read_json_files(folder_path)
```

And this is the error message I am receiving:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I am not sure what is causing this error or how to fix it. Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Here a example of my data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h2J-e0cF9IbbWVO8ugrXMGdQTn-dGtsA/view?usp=sharing

**Update**:
There was a file with a different format than the others and therefore it was not read correctly, I have deleted it. Now it gives me a different error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 20
     17     return pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)
     19 folder_path = 'C:/Users/gusta/Desktop/business/Emprendimiento'
---> 20 combined_dataframe = read_json_files(folder_path)

Cell In[1], line 17, in read_json_files(folder_path)
     15         df = load_json_to_dataframe(os.path.join(folder_path, json_file))
     16         dataframes.append(df)
---> 17 return pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)

File c:\Users\gusta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:331, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    325 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    326     warnings.warn(
    327         msg.format(arguments=_format_argument_list(allow_args)),
    328         FutureWarning,
    329         stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
    330     )
--> 331 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File c:\Users\gusta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py:381, in concat(objs, axis, join, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    159 """
    160 Concatenate pandas objects along a particular axis.
    161 
...
    186 return self._blknos

File c:\Users\gusta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\internals.pyx:718, in pandas._libs.internals.BlockManager._rebuild_blknos_and_blklocs()

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 966. KiB for an array with shape (123696,) and data type int64
```

Comment: The error is often seen when the file is empty. Use try-catch or pdb to find out which file is causing the error.

Comment: Yes, there was a file with a different format than the others and therefore it was not read correctly, I have deleted it, but the error change. I'll do an update right now.

Comment: In cases like these - where you are reading multiple files with a possibility of one throwing an error - it's best to use `try/except` and iterate through all of the files that _work_, and print out the name of the all the files that did not. This way you can explore the "broken" files independently, and chase down where they are failing at.

Comment: @Felipe It's a good idea, I'll try it and if it doesn't work I'll post a new update. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution through the following code, and the main issues were:

1. I was not correctly specifying the layers of the .json file, so
   loading it completely was consuming too much memory.
2. Due to the above reason, I made the code apply to one product
   category at a time. This way it worked.

So, I was able to solve the problem by specifying the correct layers to extract from the .json file, rather than extracting the entire file and filtering later. Additionally, I modified the code to process only one product category at a time to improve memory usage.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import os

# Function to load a JSON file into a Pandas DataFrame
def load_json_to_dataframe(json_file_path):
    with open(json_file_path, 'r') as json_file:
        # Load JSON file into a Python dictionary
        doc = json.load(json_file)
        # Extract the creation time of the file
        file_creation_time = os.path.getctime(json_file_path)
        # Convert the creation time to a datetime object
        file_creation_time = pd.to_datetime(file_creation_time, unit='s')
        # Normalize the JSON data and add the creation time as a new column
        df = pd.json_normalize(doc, meta=['id', 'title', 'condition', 'permalink',
                                          'category_id', 'domain_id', 'thumbnail',
                                          'currency_id', 'price', 'sold_quantity',
                                          'available_quantity', ['seller', 'id'],
                                          ['seller', 'nickname'], ['seller', 'permalink'],
                                          ['address', 'state_name'], ['address', 'city_name']])
        # Reorder the columns to have the file_creation_time column after the id column
        df = df[['id', 'title', 'condition', 'permalink', 'category_id', 'domain_id',
                 'thumbnail', 'currency_id', 'price', 'sold_quantity', 'available_quantity',
                 'seller.id', 'seller.nickname', 'seller.permalink', 'address.state_name',
                 'address.city_name']]
        # Add the file creation time column to the DataFrame
        df['file_creation_time'] = file_creation_time
        return df

# Function to read multiple JSON files into a single Pandas DataFrame
def read_json_files(folder_path, categories=None, batch_size=1000):
    if categories is None:
        # If no categories are specified, read all files that end in '.json'
        json_files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith('.json')]
    else:
        # If categories are specified, read only files that correspond to those categories
        json_files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith('.json') and any(category in f for category in categories)]
    # Split the list of files into batches of a given size
    batches = [json_files[i:i+batch_size] for i in range(0, len(json_files), batch_size)]
    # Read each batch of files into a list of DataFrames
    dfs = []
    for batch in batches:
        batch_dfs = [load_json_to_dataframe(os.path.join(folder_path, f)) for f in batch]
        dfs.append(pd.concat(batch_dfs, ignore_index=True))
    # Concatenate all DataFrames into a single DataFrame
    return pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)

# Specify the categories of files to read and the folder path
categories = ['MLC4922.json']
folder_path = 'C:/path/to/folder/files'

# Read the JSON files into a single DataFrame
combined_dataframe = read_json_files(folder_path, categories)
```